# Omaha Hi/Lo hand question comparing two low hands

Tags: cash-game, hand, heads-up, omaha-hi-lo, soft-question

We had a hand that came up this past weekend in Omaha Hi/Lo with regards to Low.  The board was A, 7, 8, J, K.   Player A's low cards were 2, 5 while Player B's were 3, 4.  My opinion is that player A's 5 cards in revers was 8,7,5,2,A lost to player B's hand of 8,7,4,3,A.   The 4 being lower than the 5 gave player B the win.

Others say that the 2 of player A gave that player the win, even though ever other hand they agree that a low hand with the highest card of a 7, beats any hand with the highest card of an 8 and so forth.

Please give me the official ruling on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Lo work in Omaha Hi-Lo](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-does-lo-work-in-omaha-hi-lo)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to compare Omaha low hands is to treat the cards as numbers (with Ace = 1) and order high to low. In your example:

- Player A has 87521
- Player B has 87431

Ordered numerically, Player B's 87431 is clearly a lower number than Player A's 87521, so Player B has the winning low hand.

This is all covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_hold_%27em#:%7E:text=Low%20hands%20can%20thus%20be%20read%20as%20numbers), but I'm adding this as an answer rather than a comment because I find the "numerical ordering" concept helpful.